# Shipping fields not showing up after upgrade to Magento 2.2.3

Tags: magento2, javascript, extensions

Upgrade from Magento 2.1.6 -> 2.2.3 and PHP 5.6 to 7.0.20

After the upgrade seems like most things are working find except the /checkout/ page which is having trouble loading the shipping field forms:

**Expected:**

[image: Expected]

**Actual:**

[image]

Not sure what exactly is causing this, getting this JS error which seems important:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "if: function (){return isFormInline }"
Message: Unable to process binding "template: function (){return shippingFormTemplate }"
Message: shippingFormTemplate is not defined
    at template (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout.js:2624), <anonymous>:3:61)
    at init (knockout.js:5023)
    at knockout.js:2989
    at Object.ignore (knockout.js:1249)
    at knockout.js:2988
    at Object.arrayForEach (knockout.js:151)
    at applyBindingsToNodeInternal (knockout.js:2974)
    at applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal (knockout.js:2854)
    at applyBindingsToDescendantsInternal (knockout.js:2836)
    at Object.ko.applyBindingsToDescendants (knockout.js:3052)
```

The standard Magento module for checkout is used on this page and it's not overwritten by the theme or anything else as far as I know and the JSON data coming from the server seems to be OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue which was caused by theme overwriting Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/shipping.js file. This file seems to have changed in 2.2.3.

Comment: Thanks, deleting that file at the theme level has seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that in my case the standard `Magento_Checkout/shipping` module was overwritten by the extension [Ced_StorePickup](https://cedcommerce.com/magento-2-extensions/store-pickup) on Magento v2.2.6

After analyzing the error message `shippingFormTemplate is not defined`, and comparing `pub/static/frontend/Ced/ced/en_US/Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping.js` with `pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping.js` it quickly became obvious that the former was missing the definition of `shippingFormTemplate` unlike the latter.

The solution was to add the missing variables `shippingFormTemplate`, `shippingMethodListTemplate`, and `shippingMethodItemTemplate` in `app/code/Ced/StorePickup/view/frontend/web/js/shipping-override.js` copied from `pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping.js`

Here's a relevant code snippet from `app/code/Ced/StorePickup/view/frontend/web/js/shipping-override.js`:

```
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping',
            shippingFormTemplate: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/form',
            shippingMethodListTemplate: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/shipping-method-list',
            shippingMethodItemTemplate: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/shipping-method-item'
        },
```

After adding the three variables as above, I ran the following commands:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f mk_MK
bin/magento cache:flush
```

Deleting Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/shipping.js did not help, but tgor's and chomazambia's hint was very helpful in diagnosing the problem.